# Looking for count down clock in CEWP using html/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, content-editor-web-part

I am looking to insert a count down clock in content editor web part using html / jQuery. Did any one ever do this? I am unable to figure out how to start as am not a pro in scripting.

Comment: [Help with Dual Javascript countdown clock](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/158703/help-with-dual-javascript-countdown-clock)

Comment: Thanks Atish that link has done my job as per required. Apprciate your share :-)

Answer (score 2):

[This site](http://www.timeanddate.com/clocks/freecountdown.html) allows you to create a timer, then it outputs the code for you. You can edit as needed.