# Update a column in SharePoint 2013 with the current date on a daily basis

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, javascript, date

I am trying to update the date in a column to show Today's date and automatically update it every day in SharePoint 2013.

Can someone help? 
How to achieve this?

A front-end or client-side approach would be best.

Comment: You need a trigger to update, do you want a back-end (.Net) trigger or a front-end? (user display a View (and code update fields)

Comment: Could you please advise on the front-end approach? How would I edit the View?

Answer (score 1):

The `Today()` **function** inside a Calculated Column Formula is correct,
**But only if the Item (or formula itself) was updated TODAY**

Much written about:

- [How to use Today and Me in Calculated column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/151144/how-to-use-today-and-me-in-calculated-column/151336#151336)

So your use-case requires a trigger to update the Items daily, either a workflow,

OR Client Side code:

[Create unique number with ListItem [ID] and [Today] age in Calculated Column Formula](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/160426/create-unique-number-with-listitem-id-and-today-age-in-calculated-column-for/160447#160447)

Explains how to do it from a Calculated Column in a view; but the encapsulated JavaScript code can be used in any SharePoint page.  CSR in a ListView the more obvious.

#### Related:

- [Calculated formulas for tracking progress](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/162343/calculated-formulas-for-tracking-progress/162344#162344)
- [Help with Dual Javascript countdown clock](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/158703/help-with-dual-javascript-countdown-clock/159853#159853)
- [Can I add a start workflow link to a column in a list view?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/150787/can-i-add-a-start-workflow-link-to-a-column-in-a-list-view/150796#150796)

Comment: Why should the formula be updated? I think Today() would work even without updating since it is just JavaScript getting rendered by the browser, no?

Comment: The Today() function **inside** a Calculated Column Formula. That is the SharePoint Today() function

Comment: Ah! I thought Today() was a JS function. Oops... my bad.

Comment: Note: there is no SharePoint documentation on this Today() function; it does exist since 2013