# Calculated Field - Open/Today Until Closed

Tags: calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I have seen a few tickets with this general solution, but I have a thought about how this would work and how I would like it to update and need some input on how to make it work.

I have a trouble ticket. I need to know the number of days this ticket is open.

**I need to know:**

**1.) Number of Days Open from Opening Day to Today**

**2.) Number of Days Open from Opening Day to Closed**

**3.) Stop after Closed**

and I need both of these to exist within a If/Else type of statement so that it stops counting once Status = Closed

From what I have read the problem is refreshing. If I somehow refreshed tickets with a workflow, I would be alright with that, and then just have an end workflow to where if any updates were made to a ticket after it was closed the dates wouldn't change. Any input would be helpful, but I think this approach makes sense, just not sure how to implement something like this.

Comment: ClientSide solution: Build a report using REST api and moment.js. Add export to excel capability.

Comment: You can set calculated column as mentioned in this answer (It will shows the days count as per daily basis): http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/171222/count-not-updating-in-calculated-column/171482#171482

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you're thinking will work. You'd have to write a workflow to pause for 24 hours, then update the item so that the calculated columns got updated. Or you might just set the values from the workflow rather than using a calculated column. If you're in 2013, you could loop the 24-hour pause in a while statement to stop running once the ticket is closed. In 2010, you'd have to just have the workflow run on every edit and the first step of the workflow would be to terminate the workflow if the ticket is closed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with client-side code take inspiration from:

- [How to use Today and Me in Calculated column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/151144/how-to-use-today-and-me-in-calculated-column/151336#151336)
- [Create unique number with ListItem [ID] and [Today] age in Calculated Column Formula](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/160426/create-unique-number-with-listitem-id-and-today-age-in-calculated-column-for/160447#160447)
- [Calculated formulas for tracking progress](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/162343/calculated-formulas-for-tracking-progress/162344#162344)
- [Help with Dual Javascript countdown clock](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/158703/help-with-dual-javascript-countdown-clock/159853#159853)
- [Can I add a start workflow link to a column in a list view?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/150787/can-i-add-a-start-workflow-link-to-a-column-in-a-list-view/150796#150796)